# Question about qiskit optimizer in Portfolio Optimization

Tags: qiskit

We tried running the Portfolio Optimization code using qiskit with the optimizer: `Sequential Least Squares Programming optimizer`.

For 10 stocks, it ran fine. But for 21 stocks it hung up. Could anyone suggest why so?

Comment: what do you mean hang up, are there any error pop up.

Comment: What's up with weird capitalization and overall bad formatting? You should provide more details about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 10 stocks it uses a less number of qubits than for the 21 stocks. Try to get the number of variables your model is using , by get_num_var , and then use the appropriate backend for it to run. There are many quantum simulators provided by IBM, ranging from 32 qubits to 5000 qubits.